# ExtJS5 How to use ViewController and ViewModel without SenchaCmd

Tags: viewmodel, alias, viewcontroller, extjs5

### Question

I used to use extJs 4 with MVC, now I want to change to extjs 5 and add ViewModel and ViewController into it. But I have no privilege to install SenchaCmd to generate and compile the app as the guides says. I wonder if SenchaCmd is necessarily in ExtJs5, because when I add a ViewController for a view, there's error - Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: controller.mainViewController.

If there's no SenchaCmd but I want to add ViewController and ViewModel for my app, what should I do?

### Code

#### MyApp.view.main.MainView.js

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MainView',

    //  requires: ['main.MainViewModel'],
    controller: 'mainViewController',
    //    viewModel: {
    //        type: 'mainView'
    //    },

    tabPosition: 'left',
    tabRotation: 0,

    defaults: {
        textAlign: 'left',
        bodyPadding: 15
    },

    items: [{
        title: 'test',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            listeners: {
                onClick: 'onTest'
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

#### CaTools.view.main.MainViewController.js

```js
Ext.define('CaTools.view.main.MainViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.mainViewController',

    onTest: function() {
        console.log('test -- ');
    }
});
```

#### Error

> `Error - Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: controller.mainViewController`

Many Thanks!!

Comment: You need to require the full class name for the VM.

Comment: Thank you @Evan Trimboli, I thought it was because of the SenchaCmd until your reminder! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

All that Sencha CMD is doing for you - *in this context, anyway* - is building a bootstrap file. As part of that, it knows that when it brings in a View, and it sees that the view has a viewModel and controller attribute, it looks for ViewModel and ViewController classes by convention (Model and Controller).

So you can do that yourself. Simply `require` the ViewModel and ViewController classes from within your View, just as you would `require` any other class.

(As an alternative - define the ViewModel and ViewController as additional classes inside the View's Javascript file; that way it's always loaded when the View is)